# How can I filter this signal in mathematica

Tags: plotting, signal-processing

Given the transfer function $H(z) = \frac{1}{4}(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2}+z^{-3})$ and the input signal $x[n] = \cos(\frac{\pi}{50}n)+\cos(\frac{4\pi}{5}n)$, how can I find the output signal $y[n]$ in mathematica?

---

### What I tried

```
H[z_] := 1/4 (1 + 1/z + 1/z^2 + 1/z^3)
x[n_] := Cos[π/50 n] + Cos[(4 π)/5 n]


zt = ZTransform[x[n], n, z, Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers, n >= 0, z >= 0}];

InverseZTransform[Abs[zt * H[z]], z, n, 
                  Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers, n >= 0, z >= 0}]
```

However, I get a bunch of error messages from this.

> ```
> Assumptions::mepreal :  "In attempting to decide whether a solution <<...>.
> is real, $MaxExtraPrecision  50.` was encountered. The solution was assumed real. 
> Increasing the value of $MaxExtraPrecision may help resolve the uncertainty.>>
> ```

I'm really not sure how to filter this signal in Mathematica.

Comment: I don't understand what filtering is in this context, but if you drop the Abs, the InverseZTransform gives a reasonable result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mathematica considers the unilateral (or one-sided) z-transform of a sequence $x[n]$, that is, $X(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x[n] z^{-n}$, which implies a causal sequence $x[n]$ (defined only for non-negative $n$). In signal processing applications, where non-causal sequences are often considered, it is more convenient to use the two-sided version of the z-transform, i.e., $X(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x[n] z^{-n}$.

However, even if Mathematica had an implementation of the two-sided (inverse) z-transform, in the majority of cases (w.r.t. signal processing applications at least) there is no need to employ the formal definition of the transform as "standard" sequences are typically involved which can be simply handled by inspection.

In your case, it is easy to see that the inverse z-transform of $H(z)$ is $h[n]=\frac{1}{4}(\delta[n]+\delta[n-1]+\delta[n-2]+\delta[n-3])$. It follows at once that the output of the filter will be 
$y[n]=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^3 x[n-k]$.

Plotting the input and output sequences is trivial. (The discrete-time signals are plotted as piecewise linear for visualization purposes.)

```
x[n_] := Cos[\[Pi]/50 n] + Cos[(4 \[Pi])/5 n];
y[n_] := Sum[x[n - k], {k, 0, 3}]/4.;

Grid[{{   
 DiscretePlot[x[n], {n, -50, 50}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {"n", "x[n]"}, ImageSize -> 250, Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> None],
 DiscretePlot[y[n], {n, -50, 50}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {"n", "y[n]"}, ImageSize -> 250, Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> None]    
}}]
```

[image]

Note that the output of the filter has suppressed the higher frequency cosine term of the input signal

Answer (score 5):

You could use the built-in functions `OutputResponse` or `RecurrenceFilter`.

```
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[1/4 (1 + z^-1 + z^-2 + z^-3), z^-1, 
  SamplingPeriod -> 1]

OutputResponse[N@tfm, 
Cos[(π n)/50] + Cos[(4 π n)/5], {n, 0, 200}] // ListLinePlot

RecurrenceFilter[N@tfm, Table[Cos[(π n)/50] + Cos[(4 π n)/5],
{n, 0, 200}]] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Comment: I like your response to the question but why have you used z^-1 in the transfer function rather than z?

Comment: Simply because that is the transfer function in the question.

Comment: I don’t think I was clear - my fault. You wrote `TransferFunctionModel[1/4(1+z^-1+z^-2+z^-3), z^-1, SamplingPeriod->1]` I was expecting `TransferFunctionModel[1/4(1+z^-1+z^-2+z^-3), z, SamplingPeriod->1]`. The difference is the 2nd argument where you have `z^-1` and I have `z`. I noticed this because I tried a `BodePlot` of your transfer function and it comes up with a bunch of errors, but if I change to `z` then `BodePlot` works but `OutputResponse` doesn’t.

Comment: With $z^{-1}$ the transfer function is considered as a polynomial in $z^{-1}$, whereas with $z$ it is a polynomial in $z$, which has the effect of adding additional poles and zeros.

In either case I don't get any error with `OutputResponse` but with $z^{-1}$ `BodePlot` returns an empty plot. What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using 11 on a Mac. For `z`: `OutputResponse` hangs (CPU usage maxed out - I have to abort), but `BodePlot` looks correct. For `1/z`: `OutputResponse` looks good, but `BodePlot` has a bunch of errors and gives empty plots.

Comment: That's not what I experience on a Mac and `$VersionNumber` 11.4. Probably you are using 11.0.